# Is it possible for any value of incident angle (except 90°) that the refracted ray goes along the normal (rarer to denser case)?

Tags: optics, refraction

[image]

I was going through the topic *critical angle*. When light travels from denser to rarer medium & when angle is critical angle, it goes along the surface of separation, *i.e. grazing emergence*.

Will the ray coincide with normal, when the medium is rarer to denser with a smaller angle of incidence?

If yes, then what will happen when we further decrease the incidence angle?

Comment: if you know the law of diffraction $\sin(a)/\sin(b)=n you can see that a never can be 0 so the angle 0.

Comment: why have you stated except $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians? Did you mean except $0$?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the ray will coincide, but the second part of your question can be answered easily.

By Snell's law,

$$\frac{\sin\left(i\right)}{\sin\left(r\right)}=n_{21}.$$

For the refracted ray to make an angle $0$ with the normal, $\sin(r)=0$.

If $\sin(r)$ becomes zero, for Snell's law to be valid, $\sin(i)$ should also be zero (actually, they will be tending to zero), which means you have to shine light perpendicular to the surface.

[image]

You obviously can see why we cannot make the angle any smaller than that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Snell's law of refraction i.e. $\sin(a)/\sin(b)=n$, you can see that $sin(a)$ never can be $0$  unless $sin(b)$ is zero. So the angle will be $0$ in both media.

You can inverse any way of the light so turn the direction of your light in the last picture around and see, that it is impossible.

Comment: It's refraction, not diffraction.

Answer (score 0):

I like to look at questions like this from the perspective of symmetry.  If you look at your second sketch  in reverse, you can see that it would require a *symmetrical* ray to become *asymmetrical* upon refraction.  Symmetries are always preserved in classical physics: there is no reason for a ray to "make a choice" to turn even slightly in any one  direction more than another direction.

So the answer is "no", an angled ray will never exit a uniform slab of material in a direction perpendicular to the surface.